# What is the react function that's called when my mouse enters the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

In chrome dev tools, I consistently see a 100ms blip on the performance timeline when my mouse first enters the DOM in my React project. The function call is listed as a mouseover event callback in the react DOM, but I can't find any info in the react docs about why this event occurs. Is it because events are delegated to the window in react, or is it background work that needs to be done to prepare for other events?

It's off-putting to see such an intense function call that I never called for, especially if I am planning my own work to be done at the same time. If anyone has any insights, I would be grateful!

[image]

**EDIT: It doesn't always happen under mouseover. Sometimes it is just a function call.**

[image]

Comment: it is called `onMouseOver`. Are you sure your component or external modules do not use it ?

Comment: I have no window level mouseover events that I know of.

Comment: Chrome dev tools would tell me if I had any onMouseOver handlers, but the timeline is empty with the exception of what is shown

Answer (score 0):

a `onmouseover` is the synthetic javascript event that is being registered here when you mouse is entering the DOM. These events have corresponding synthetic React events, which can be found on this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html). Most of the events from JS on a DOM have a corresponding event in React. You can find all of them enlisted on the given [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

Comment: I know about synthetic events already. The question is about why react creates an event without me asking it to. Is it event delegation?

Comment: well its kind of the event registration for the React Event System. It helps react to wrap the synthetic event and provide a React version of it which you can use to work with the JSX syntax and these React events will correspond to the synthetic JS events on the DOM. Normal synthetic events wont work with React JSX syntax. They have to wrapper in events from React event system. Have a read at the link I have shared. You will get a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you! That probably answers my question

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if you are happy with explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be part of the answer as well. Taken directly from the source code. I think this 'blip' is setting up the React event emitter. So React is using event delegation and this emitter is responsible for delegating.

[image]